# Creating HTTPS enabled reverse proxy for GoEthereum

Tags: metamask

On metamask, I want to connect to my private geth with SSL, because ios/android needs it.

```
server {

listen [::]:443 ssl ; # managed by Certbot
listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot


   ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain.net/fullchain.pem;
   ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain.net/privkey.pem;



include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot
server_name mydomain.net;


location /rpc {
  proxy_redirect off;
  proxy_pass    http://mydomain.net:9000;
}

}
```

sudo systemctl start nginx
with no error.

but on metamask, I cant connect to.

https://mydomain.com:9000
networkId: 2000

metamask says
"Could not fetch chain ID. Is your RPC URL correct?"

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using Nginx, this might be easier using Caddy web server that comes with Let's Encrypt integration. [Here are some example configurations for Caddy](https://caddyserver.com/).

Here is an example Caddyfile HTTPS/reverse proxy configuration for any EVM compatible node.

```
# Will automatically get TLS certificate for mynode.example.com
# on Caddy startup
# if your server DNS is configured properly 
mynode.example.com {

        # Add password protection
        # https://caddyserver.com/docs/caddyfile/directives/basicauth
        basicauth {
                admin JDJhJDE0JGEuVEZqOWp1QU9Jd0l5OTRFOW0wWU9wSlVBekd4UmNEM0w3eGFWekxBUEkvR1JRZkpZWmdh
        }

        reverse_proxy 127.0.0.1:8545

}
```

[Some more examples of running nodes can be found in this repository](https://github.com/tradingstrategy-ai/ethereum-blockchain-docker-compose).

Caddy can also do automatic TLS certificate (HTTPS) for your connection.