# Exposing RPC port: how to expose rpc on [::]:8545 and not only on localhost

Tags: go-ethereum, rpc, full-node

I  have a simple question but I cannot find the problem.
I want to expose the RPC port of my node in my local network (so that I can access it from another computer).

I run the node with :
`geth --http --http.corsdomain=* --http.api eth,net,admin,web3,debug --datadir /opt/ethereum/execution --maxpeers 16 --authrpc.jwtsecret /opt/ethereum/consensus/prysm/jwt.hex`

but

`lsof -i -P -n | grep 8545`

still outputs

`geth TCP 127.0.0.1:8545 (LISTEN)`

and not something like

`[::]:8545`

as I want it to be.

Do you know why the corsdomain parameter does not change anything ? Thank you in advance

Comment: You can also add [HTTP Basic Auth username/password](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/130722/620) to your JSON-RPC connection. This way bots won't hammer your node.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was not looking at the right thing. I wanted

```
[::]:8545
```

Which just need to add the option

```
--http.addr [::]
```

in the Geth comand.

Answer (score 0):

That's a command I ended up to boot a node for my aims:

```
geth --allow-insecure-unlock --http --http.addr "0.0.0.0" --port $NODE1_PORT_UDP_TCP --http.corsdomain '*' --authrpc.port $NODE1_PORT_RPC --http.port $NODE1_PORT --http.api admin,personal,eth,net,web3  --datadir ./node1/data --miner.gasprice 0 --verbosity 3 &
```

Please note `--allow-insecure-unlock` is open node for some security attacks. As well as `--http.corsdomain` does too. They are here only for development stage - deployment and run in the production would require extra efforts to cover this security risks.